# How to use custom color for step label string in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, customization, stepper

I wanna use Stepper in a black background. Accordingly, need to change the step label string from the primary color (grey) to a light one (white).
I applied a custom style to StepLabel as below:

```
const ColorlibStepLabel = styled(StepLabel)(() => ({
  [`&.${stepLabelClasses.active}`]: {
    [`& .${stepLabelClasses.label}`]: {
      color: '#fff',
    },
  },
  [`&.${stepLabelClasses.completed}`]: {
    [`& .${stepLabelClasses.label}`]: {
      color: '#fff',
    },
  },
  [`& .${stepLabelClasses.label}`]: {
    color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
  },
}));
```

After this, I was able to get white color for disabled state but not for completed and active state.

[image: current behavior of customized stepper]

I'd like to know the correct way how to change the color for completed and active step label string.

https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-field-nbbcy

Answer (score 0):

```
const ColorlibStepLabel = styled(StepLabel)(() => ({
  [`& .${stepLabelClasses.label}`]: {
    [`&.${stepLabelClasses.completed}`]: {
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    },
    [`&.${stepLabelClasses.active}`]: {
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    },
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
  },
}));
```

This works! 
[@amanzrx4](https://github.com/amanzrx4) at GitHub published the solution.